# PyQt5 : How to make a button close the gui after clicking

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

Here is my code for the click button:

```
run_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run")
def main():
    print ('Starting Program')
run_btn.clicked.connect(main)
```

But after I click "Run", it just prints "Starting Program" again and again, and the GUI window doesn't disappear:

[image: screenshot]

How can I make the button print it once and go on with the program ?

**I am using PyQt5 and Python 3.4.0**

Comment: It's hard to tell from this snippet. Could you provide a minimal working example that reproduces undesired behavior?

Comment: @mFoxRU http://prntscr.com/eek8ws here's what i mean... the gui window doesnt disappear...

Comment: call `close()` method of main window

Comment: `run_btn.clicked.connect(mainwindow.close)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the `QPushButton` is inside the main widget (in the example `QWidget`), to close the window we use the `close()`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

line1_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
line2_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

run_btn=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Run")
def main():
    print ('Starting Program')
    w.close()

run_btn.clicked.connect(main)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(line1_edit)
layout.addWidget(line2_edit)
layout.addWidget(run_btn)
w.setLayout(layout)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yo man what does the sys.ext(app.exec()) do ? and thanks for the help :)

Comment: It sets the exit code of your Python script to the exit code of the Qt app. So if something bad happens, you get a nonzero exit code. (In Bash, you can run `echo $?` to print the exit code of the previous command.)

Comment: When running from Python IDE such as Spyder, the Python console is still operating even after the app closed. Is there any way to force app.quit() to be called after the button is pushed ?